# SQL Having Statement with a 'CASE columnx IN (select statement)'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 query that is returning correct data if I don't add a `CASE` statement to the below `HAVING u.urlid in (SELECT ... )` clause.

Basically I would like the following query to return everything in the `HAVING` part of the SQL statement if the variable `@IDList = '0'`

The statement below is filtered by `@IDList` in the `HAVING u.urlid in` clause and works as expected, but I need to add something in the `HAVING` clause that returns all data `FROM urlcat inner join URL ON URLCat.URLID = URL.URLID` if `@IDList = '0'`.

```
declare @IDList NVARCHAR(MAX) = '0'
declare @Count INTEGER = 1
declare @RowIndex INTEGER = 0
declare @PageSize INTEGER = 1000000
declare @wordList NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

Set @IDList = '110713'
Set @wordList = 'nova'  

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT t2.URLID, t2.CategorySummary, t2.Title, t2.[Description], t2.URL 
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(ws.equiv_word)) AS [ROW_NUMBER],
    u.URLID, CategorySummary = dbo.SQL_CLR_Aggregate(ws.word + ', ' + CAST(ws.[order] AS NVARCHAR) ),
    u.Title, u.[Description], u.URL 
    FROM URLCat uc inner join word_senses ws ON uc.CatID = ws.word_sense inner join URL u ON uc.URLID = u.URLID 
    GROUP BY u.urlid, u.Title, u.[Description], u.URL
    -- NOTE: This is the part I'm having issues with
    HAVING u.urlid in 
    (
      SELECT URLCat.URLID 
      FROM urlcat inner join URL ON URLCat.URLID = URL.URLID 
      WHERE CatID in (SELECT * FROM dbo.bigintlist_to_tbl(@IDList))
      GROUP BY urlcat.urlid 
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT catid)=@Count)
     )
     AS t2
 WHERE t2.[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @RowIndex + 1 AND @RowIndex + @PageSize AND 
 (@wordList = '' OR (t2.Title like '%' + @wordList  + '%' OR t2.Description like '%' + @wordList  + '%'))
 ORDER BY t2.[ROW_NUMBER]
```

I have tried the following case statement which I added to the `HAVING` clause which I though would work:

```
HAVING u.urlid in 
    (
    CASE WHEN @IDList = '0' THEN u.urlid
    ELSE
    (SELECT URLCat.URLID 
    FROM urlcat inner join URL ON URLCat.URLID = URL.URLID 
    WHERE CatID in (SELECT * FROM dbo.bigintlist_to_tbl(@IDList))
    GROUP BY urlcat.urlid 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT catid)=@Count) END
    )
) AS t2
```

However when I add this `CASE` statement it gives me an error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I can confirm that the statement works:

- if I **don't** have the `CASE` statement
- if I have **only** (i.e. returns everything)  `HAVING u.urlid in u.urlid`
- if I have **only** (i.e. Filtered by @IDList)

  `HAVING u.urlid in ( SELECT URLCat.URLID FROM urlcat inner join URL ON URLCat.URLID = URL.URLID WHERE CatID in (SELECT * FROM dbo.bigintlist_to_tbl(@IDList)) GROUP BY urlcat.urlid HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT catid)=@Count))`

but I need to do one or the other depending on whether `@IDList = '0'`

Can any one give me some options or reasons why my `CASE` statement is not working within the `HAVING` clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `case` doesn't work because it can only result in a single value, not the result from a subquery.

You could use a union in the subquery to return different results depending on the variable:

```
HAVING u.urlid in (
  SELECT URLCat.URLID 
  FROM urlcat inner join URL ON URLCat.URLID = URL.URLID 
  WHERE CatID in (SELECT * FROM dbo.bigintlist_to_tbl(@IDList))
  GROUP BY urlcat.urlid 
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT catid)=@Count) and @IDList <> '0'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT u.urlid WHERE @IDList = '0'
)
```

Comment: Brilliant... That works... Just need to remove the bracket at the end of the HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT catid)=@Count) 

Sorry I don't have enough points to upvote you :(

Comment: I have one small problem now that Im not sure how to correct based on your answer. Now that I have the Union All in there the 't2.[ROW_NUMBER]' seems to be all out of wack... and Im not sure why or how to correct this? Can you help

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as a compound statement:

```
 HAVING @IDList = '0' or
        u.urlid in (SELECT URLCat.URLID 
                    FROM urlcat inner join
                         URL
                         ON URLCat.URLID = URL.URLID 
                    WHERE CatID in (SELECT * FROM dbo.bigintlist_to_tbl(@IDList))
                    GROUP BY urlcat.urlid 
                    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT catid)=@Count) END
                   )
) AS t2
```

I think the logic is easier to follow this way.

Note that you could also do this in the `where` clause rather than the `having` clause.

Comment: I have one small problem now that Im not sure how to correct based on your answer. Now that I have the Union All in there the 't2.[ROW_NUMBER]' seems to be all out of wack... and Im not sure why or how to correct this? Can you help

Comment: Thanks I have used both answers and both work really well... I think Gordon's answer is, as he says, easier to understand.

Also I have fixed my issue with the row number by inserting the data into a @tempTable and then selecting the data with a row number out of that table. Ugly but it works.